# putty vim all hotkey mapping

Tags: linux, terminal, shortcut, putty

I'm using Ubuntu server.
And I'm using putty to remote control my pc.

It's well connected and good.
However,
there is 'hotkey problem'

I tried "shift + arrow' to move cursor, it didn't work.
I searched web and there are small solutions.
I can't change all hotkeys using this methods.

But, I want to use same hotkey setting with putty and without putty.
If not, it is too confusing to me.

I don't know how can I call my vim keymap (when I use without putty)
Currently,'shift + arrow' s are moving cursor

I tried to change putty->terminal->keyboard->the function keys and keypad->Xterm R6 and linux.
But it didn't work.

Is there any good solutions?

Comment: Hmm… What is `shift + arrow`? I don't think vim has such a “hotkey”.

Comment: arrows are located in left side of the numpad, by using this I can move cursor very fast

Comment: I doubt this is a vim hotkey. Probably that has something to do with your terminal.